# Type 'http://schemas.domain.com:Ssn' is not declared, or is not a simple type when using multiple schemas

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have two schemas, one with main definition of the object, and another one has as definiton for the types that are not simple type (string, int, decimal for example)

that is called common.xsd

When i validate, it adds both schemas but it doesn´t find the types in the included file.

Main.Xsd holds:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>
```

and this is the validation function:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(xsdFile);
            XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(File.OpenRead(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Schemas\\Main.xsd")), OnXsdSyntaxError);
            XmlSchema schema2 = XmlSchema.Read(File.OpenRead(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Schemas\\Common.xsd")), OnXsdSyntaxError);


                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;

                //þurfum að adda common.xsd líka !
                settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
                settings.Schemas.Add(schema2);
                settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(OnXsdSyntaxError);

                using (XmlReader validator = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))
                {
                    while (validator.Read())
                        isValid = true;
                }
```

The error is:

Type 'http://schemas.domain.com:Ssn' is not declared, or is not a simple type.

So clearly it is not adding the scheme2 file ad therefor not finding definition for this custom types.

I would really appreciate help with this, because i´m forced to use multiple XSD files in this validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your include will only import types from the other schema which share the same namespace as the types in your main schema.

If you want to import types from a different namespace use the namespace attribute:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Common.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.domain.com" />
```

Also the schemaLocation attribute is completely optional.